# HttpClient throws TruncatedChunkException accessing large chunked resource - why I got this message?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, jgit

I tried to do clone in my code with jgit.
I do it for long repo and I got

```
HttpClient throws TruncatedChunkException accessing large chunked resource
from HTTPCLIENT.
```

what is the reason for this ?

Comment: Please show the code that clones the repository. Ideally, you would be able to share the repository as well. Otherwise, these types of errors are hard to track down.

Comment: I will do it but in general what is the reason for this error ?

Comment: The chunk was truncated. The server didn't send the entire chunk that it promised to send in the chunk header. Or the connection got terminated early by the peer for some other reason, possibly to do with a proxy or a firewall.